# Evento onClick en React afecta a todos los elementos hijo

Tags: reactjs

Quiero mostrar un modal con la info de un item ("ResultsTag") de una lista al hacer click sobre el.

Resulta que al hacer click sobre la "ResultsTag" el evento me devuelve el elemento hijo sobre el que hice click y no el "ResultsTag" completo, por lo que no me es posible identificar la "ResultsTag" que debo mostrar.

Aca el codigo:

```js
_showModal = (e) => {
 console.log(e.target)
}

<div onClick={this._showModal}>
    {this._renderResultsTag()}
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @lamsarmiento y podrías mostrarnos qué hace tu función `_renderResultsTag`? Por otro lado, exactamente qué es lo que quieres recoger en `_showModal`?

Comment: _renderResultsTag solo retorna la etiqueta, que consta de un div padre (en el que puse el onClick) con varios elementos hijo.

Comment: En el showModal quiero recoger el elemento padre, es decir, el div. Con e.target me daba el elemento sobre el q hacia click y no el elemento padre que es el que quiero para poder mostrar el modal

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer mi problema era de Javascript y no de React especificamente.

Repasando las referencias de Javascript me consegui con que "target" devuelve el elemento que dispara el evento, mientras que "currentTarget" devuelve el elemento al que pertenece el evento. Con esto pude solucionar mi problema, ya que el evento lo tengo en el elemento padre. Solo debo reemplazar "target" por "currentTarget" en mi codigo

Comment: Genial!!, me salvaste la tarde, muchas gracias!!